# how to assign data in Byte type array

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

This is segment of code of 3dcpptutorials ray tracing. Can someone explain me how this lines of code works ?

As I understand it, if it's less than `0`, it stores `0` and if it's greater than `1`, then `255` and if it's between, then `value * 255`, something like that. Am I correct ?

```
colorbuffer[2] = Color.r <= 0.0f ? 0 : Color.r >= 1.0 ? 255 : (BYTE)(Color.r * 255);
colorbuffer[1] = Color.g <= 0.0f ? 0 : Color.g >= 1.0 ? 255 : (BYTE)(Color.g * 255);
colorbuffer[0] = Color.b <= 0.0f ? 0 : Color.b >= 1.0 ? 255 : (BYTE)(Color.b * 255);
```

Comment: Yes. This operation is commonly referred to as "clamping".

Comment: The code convert each color component from floating-point value in a range of `0.0` to `1.0` to an integer value between `0` and `255`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. Due to [right-to-left associativity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) of the `?:` operator, the line

```
colorbuffer[2] = Color.r <= 0.0f ? 
    0 : Color.r >= 1.0 ? 255 : (BYTE)(Color.r * 255);
```

is equivalent to this one:

```
colorbuffer[2] = Color.r <= 0.0f ? 
    0 : (Color.r >= 1.0 ? 255 : (BYTE)(Color.r * 255));
```

which in turn is equivalent to the following `if-else` block:

```
if (Color.r <= 0.0f) 
    colorbuffer[2] = 0;
else {
    if (Color.r >= 1.0) 
        colorbuffer[2] = 255;
    else
        colorbuffer[2] = (BYTE)(Color.r * 255);
}
```

There is the [`std::clamp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp) function in the standard library to do this kind of job:

```
colorbuffer[2] = (BYTE)(std::clamp(Color.r, 0.f, 1.f) * 255);
```